# cant install tor with apt-get install tor

Tags: apt, kali-linux, tor

When I try to install tor on kali linux 2017, it just says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You can search for packages with `apt-cache search <pattern>`.

Comment: I don't think tor is part of packages (depending on distribution) you may get it from official site in this case.

Comment: thank you for answer, when i put the link i sources and this comes up when i try apt-get install tor (E: Malformed entry 3 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 3 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.)

Comment: Stian, please DO NOT add information here in the comments. Please add it to your question where it can be easily found by people. (You want to make it easy for people to answer your question, I assume.)

Comment: An anonymizing tool hasn't much purpose in a distro oriented to pentesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you search for the package using:

```
$ apt search tor**
```

If it's found on the repos you'll see something like this:

> tor/stable 0.2.9.14-1 amd64
>
> > anonymizing overlay network for TCP

Then just run

```
$ sudo apt install tor
```